# Partial restore of Progress DB

Tags: restore, progress-database

I have progress .bup files for my databases The environment I am restoring too has less space and because I have no control over this environment I wish to make the databases smaller.

To do this I need to exclude certain tables from the restore process. (Alternatively I want to specify which tables to restore.)

The list for excluding is much smaller so would make more sense to specify what I wish to exclude certain tables, rather than a list of what must be  included.

Comment: I found this in DB Admin guide, has anyone used it?  --> proutil db-name [-yy n] -C BULKLOAD fd-file [-B n]

Comment: That command is for loading a binary dump into a database. It would only help if you had a binary dump from a database table to load.

Answer (score 2):

The Progress backup is a block-level image of the database & bi file, so there's no way to only restore certain tables. You'll need to

1. restore the db on a machine with enough space for the old db and the smaller db,
2. create an empty version of the db,
3. dump the required tables from the restored db,
4. load that table data into the new db file,
5. then copy the smaller db to your target machine

Comment: This is what I tried doing but you can not do a restore into a environment with less space. We work in controlled environments on a client managed AIX Unix server. :-) so it is a catch 22. And trying to copy data from one environment to another is taking days.

Comment: You have to find a machine with enough space to do a full restore - there's no way around this.